# JavaScript number rules based on multiples of 18

Tags: javascript

I am using FusionPro to create a gift ask string for an appeal letter based on a donors last gift. The letter is mailed to an area that has a high Jewish population so if a donors last gift is a multiple of 18, the ask string need to be created accordingly and only use multiples of 18. Here is my current script to create ask amounts based off of last gift. How do I work in dealing with multiples of 18?

```
//$Ask2 Round to nearest 5//

function round5(x)
{
    return Math.ceil(x/5)*5;
}

var Ask1 = Field("Last Gift "); 

var round = (round5(Ask1));


var plus10 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("10")
var plus15 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("15")
var plus20 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("20")
var plus30 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("30")
var plus50 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("50")
var plus75 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("75")
var plus100 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("100")
var plus150 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("150")
var plus250 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("250")
var plus500 = parseInt(round) + StringToNumber("500")


if (StringToNumber(round) == StringToNumber(""))
{
    return "250";
}
if (StringToNumber(round) <= StringToNumber("21"))
{
    return "45";
}
if (StringToNumber(round) >= StringToNumber("24") && StringToNumber(round) <= StringToNumber("50"))
{
    return FormatNumber("#,###", plus20);
}
if (StringToNumber(round) >= StringToNumber("49") && StringToNumber(round) <= StringToNumber("100"))
{
    return FormatNumber("#,###", plus20);
}
if (StringToNumber(round) >= StringToNumber("99") && StringToNumber(round) <= StringToNumber("300"))
{
    return FormatNumber("#,###", plus75);
}
if (StringToNumber(round) >= StringToNumber("299") && StringToNumber(round) <= StringToNumber("1000"))
{
    return FormatNumber("#,###", plus150);
}
if (StringToNumber(round) >= StringToNumber("1000"))
{
    return FormatNumber("#,###", plus250);
}
else

return "";
}

//End $Ask2 Rule//
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to find if any number is evenly divisible by another is to use the mod operator. In many languages, the operator is a % [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp)

Basically the mod operator gives you the remainder after a division operation. For example

> 4 % 2 is 0 7 % 2 is 3 Remainder 1. The result provided would be "1"
>   because that is the remainder

```js
var x = 7;
var y = 2;
var z = x % y;

console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

to find if a number is a multiple of x use the % function

so

```
if (StringToNumber(round) % 18 === 0) {
  // Number is a multiple of 18
}
```